# Search body for a string matched by regexp and replace

Tags: regex

I want search a div for a string like "12345" and then put every matched string into a span.
But when find repetitive string, just do it for first matched several time.

Here is a [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/9wz8qz7d/):

```js
function find(){
    var regex = new RegExp(/12345/g),
    list = $(".test").html().match(regex);
    console.log(list)
    for(each in list){
        replacement = $(".test").html().replace(list[each], "<span class='box'>"+list[each]+"</span>");
        $(".test").html(replacement);
    }
}

find();
```

```css
.box{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <p>
    12345 12345
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is faulty: rather than extracting all matching substrings and later iterate them performing single replacements, you may use your own regex inside a `String#replace` method to modify the substrings "inline", "on-the-match" way:

```js
function find(){
 var regex = /12345/g;
 var replacement = $(".test").html().replace(regex, "<span class='box'>$&</span>");
 $(".test").html(replacement);
}
find();
```

```css
.box{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <p>
    12345 12345
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/390emxc5/1/)), with pure JavaScript :

```
function find(){
    var motif = "12345"
    var regex = new RegExp(motif, "g")
    document.querySelector("div.test").innerHTML = document.querySelector("div.test").innerHTML.replace(regex, "<span class='box'>" + motif + "</span>") 
}

find()
```